# Why ros-kinetic-desktop package depends on gazebo?

Tags: ros, gazebo, packages

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As ros-kinetic-desktop depends on ros-kinetic-urdf-tutorial, and ros-kinetic-urdf-tutorial depends on ros-kinetic-gazebo-ros, installing ros-kinetic-desktop installs gazebo.

I think that something is wrong with that, because gazebo should be installed with ros-kinetic-desktop-full (and its dependency ros-kinetic-simulators).

Was this bug/feature introduced intentionally?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/261382/why-ros-kinetic-desktop-package-depends-on-gazebo?/) by [sergio256](https://answers.ros.org/users/30317/sergio256/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2017-05-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This was a 'mistake' and has been addressed.

See [ros-infrastructure/rep#130](https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/rep/pull/130) and the other linked tickets (such as [ros/metapackages#13](https://github.com/ros/metapackages/issues/13)).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-05-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0